# I am building a coin operated machine and am using arduino uno its working but i have to press the switch twice for credit to show on seven segment

Tags: interrupt

```
int pin1 = 8, pin2 = 9, pin3 = 10, pin4 = 11;
volatile byte  num = 0;
int coinPin = 2;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(coinPin), inc_counter, RISING );
  pinMode(pin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin4, OUTPUT);
}

void display(int num) {
  digitalWrite(pin1, bitRead(num, 1));
  digitalWrite(pin2, bitRead(num, 2));
  digitalWrite(pin3, bitRead(num, 3));
  digitalWrite(pin4, bitRead(num, 4));
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print(num);
  Serial.print("credit(s) towards balance");
  display(num);
  delay(500);
}

void inc_counter() {
  num++;
}
```

Comment: what is your question? ... not all people would ask the same question

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code supplied, you are only updating the display every half second because of the `delay(500)`. You could press the button a number of times in 500mills.

I feel it may be better to update a flag and check that in your loop to increment your value and trigger the display update.

Based on the info provided, this may help in your endeavours.

```cpp
int pin1 = 8, pin2 = 9, pin3 = 10, pin4 = 11;
int coinPin = 2;
int num = 0;
volatile bool coinFlag = false; // When true there is a coin.

void coin_present()
{
    coinFlag = true;
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(coinPin), coin_present, RISING);
    pinMode(pin1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(pin2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(pin3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(pin4, OUTPUT);
}

void display(int num)
{
    digitalWrite(pin1, bitRead(num, 1));
    digitalWrite(pin2, bitRead(num, 2));
    digitalWrite(pin3, bitRead(num, 3));
    digitalWrite(pin4, bitRead(num, 4));
}

void loop()
{
    // If the flag is set increment num and then display value.
    if (coinFlag)
    {
        //We have a coin, reset the flag first.
        coinFlag = false;

        num++;        // Increment value
        display(num); //
        Serial.print(num);
        Serial.println("credit(s) towards balance");
    }

    // No need for a delay as only `coinFlag` being `true` will update the display.
}
```

Hope this helps in someway.

Comment: Nice answer. Code that I can copy+paste into the IDE that compiles makes this answer better than most we receive.

Comment: @VE7JRO Thanks, your comment made me aware of the issue and now prompts me to double check!